# Generate debug automatically with reflection in c#

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm trying to do Bad Things with reflection in C# - automatically print debug information using an abstract class and reflection. I think I'm very close to having it work, but something's a hair off. You can see from the main below that int can be converted to a `IFormattable`, but I can't seem to get to the same place with `GetCustomAttribute`. What am I missing?

```
namespace daggonit
{
    abstract class Printer
    {
        public void Debug()
        {
            foreach (var b in GetType().GetMembers().Where(x => x.MemberType == MemberTypes.Field))
            {
                var q = b.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(IFormattable));
                Console.WriteLine(q.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    class Duck : Printer
    {
        public int wings = 2;
        public int bills = 1;

    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int q = 3;
            var r = (IFormattable)q;
            Console.WriteLine(r.ToString());
            var b = new Duck();
            b.Debug();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your error or problem?

Comment: `q` can potentially be `null`, so `q.ToString()` would throw a `NullReferenceException`

Comment: I can't seem to get the value in the attribute itself:

Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: Type passed in must be derived from System.Attribute or System.Attribute itself.

Comment: I'd like to see `2\r\n\ 1`

Comment: `IFormattable` is not an attribute.  Your `Debug` method does not have any access to the `q` and `r` variables.

Comment: It should have access to the instantiated wings and bills right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is to print out all fields you can do it like this:

```
abstract class Printer
{
    public void Debug()
    {
        foreach (var field in GetType().GetFields())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(field.GetValue(this));
        }       
    }
}
```

**Edit**: If you want to print only `IFormattable` you do something like:

```
foreach (var field in GetType().GetFields())
{
    var val = field.GetValue(this);
    if (val is IFormattable)
    { Console.WriteLine(val); }
}
```

Comment: Why is it that this works with `FieldInfo` but not `MemberInfo`

Comment: @Carbon `MemberInfo` doesn't have a way to get the members value.  For that you need to first cast it to a `PropertyInfo` or `FieldInfo`.  `MemberInfo` doesn't necessarily *have* a value, as it can be *any* member of the class, including methods, constructors, events, etc.

Comment: @Carbon You *could* use `MemberInfo` as you are, but first you'd need to cast that object to a `FieldInfo`, after which you could adapt this code to get the field's value, cast that value to an `IFormattable`, and so forth.  It's easier, in this circumstance, to just use `GetType().GetFields(...)` though and skip the cast.

Comment: The reason `MemberInfo` doesn't have a way to get a value is because both instance and static methods are members, and they do not have values, they have return values (very very different).